# Linux NFS mounted Windows network share

Tags: ubuntu, windows, nfs

I am setting up a new box (Ubuntu 12.04 LTS) to play with and I mounted (via mount.cifs) a windows network share at /mnt/common. Also added the lines to fstab, mounts just fine at boot time.

Now when I am trying to share this folder over nfs I am getting:

```
exportfs: /mnt/common does not support NFS export
```

I've played around with the mount permissions (because normally it is mounted read-only) - 777 does not help either.

Exporting /home directory works just fine.

Is that because the files are on a Windoze 2003 server? Is there any workaround around this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAIK there is no provision to "forward"  mounts in NFS.

Simply mount the CIFS share directly on what was the target system of your NFS share.

The reasons why you shouldn't even try to make this work are among others differences in how file locks are handled, how state is persisted and disconnects are handled, the case insensitivity in CIFS treats files `Foo` and `foo` the same where in NFS they're two different files, and your converting a user based authentication model (CIFS) to a system based authentication.

Comment: Got it, completely different file systems. The network configuration is a little bit tricky and mounting the cifs partition on target machine is not possible at the moment. I think I will go with WebDAV after all.